# Display date parameter as a calendar Control in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible to display date parameter in tableau as a calendar?
Thanks

Comment: When you say display as a calendar, do you mean something [like this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150101140958/http://www.tableausoftware.com/new-features/calendar-controls)?

Comment: @TimothyG. Yes please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It looks like you can](https://web.archive.org/web/20150101140958/http://www.tableausoftware.com/new-features/calendar-controls).

It looks like there is a bit of a [process to doing this](https://community.tableau.com/message/263741#263741):

> 1. Drop the Date Dimension into the Filter, select "Range of dates", and
>      hit "Next>".
> 2. Then select "Load Domain", and select Apply/OK. (I left
>      the, "Show:" as "All Values in Database".)
> 3. Then add the Quick Filter.

This should achieve what you are looking for.  Note that that post linked the same link above, but it did not direct you to the correct page.  I had to use a web archive to get it to work.

Comment: That is a solution for a filter. Not for a parameter which was in question.